# Convert large 3gp files into byte array

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert large 3gp file(>than 25mb) to byte array but it gives outofmemory exception.i am able to convert less than 25 mb 3gp file to bytearray.

File file1 = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "1.3gp");

```
            FileInputStream fis = null;

            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file1);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              try {
                while (fis.available() > 0) {
                        bos.write(fis.read());
                       }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }



           byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();


            File someFile = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/output.txt");


            FileOutputStream fos = null;

            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fos.write(bytes);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fos.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fos.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        ////
```

1. how to convert the large 3gp file into bytearray.
2. give a proper example or method.

Comment: Show us the relevant portion of your code, so that we can help.

Comment: I am using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/, specifically IOUtils.toByteArray

Answer (score 0):

Set the `-Xmx` option on the virtual machine being used to run the program to a larger value to give it more memory to work with.

You can do that as a command line option if running the program directly, or as a setting on the project in your IDE if running it from an IDE.