# secure video content stored in sdcard that other app cant access it

Tags: java, android, security

I am developing app in which it plays video stored in sdcard.
But the video stored in sdcard can be access by other video player installed in the 
android phone like media player etc.

I want that video content to be accessed only through my app only.
please give proper example or demo code snippet of doing such security system.

Comment: If you want actual security you'll need DRM.

Comment: how can i  use drm for my android app can you clarify please..

Comment: You can see this link, but it is working only for small content.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305735/convert-large-3gp-files-into-byte-array

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the file when you save it and decrypt it when you want to play the video. 
Checkout this answer

[How to encrypt and decrypt file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275311/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-file-in-android)